Unity Auth is not working with firebase to write data
I am banging my head off the wall trying to get a simple user creation flow into the front end of an app im working on.
I have email/password enabled as an auth type.. I can see in my unity logs that firebase inits but after trying to submit a Uname and Pword I will get an error a very long time after I exit play mode. Below is my Auth Code and Logs! Any help on this would be great!
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Auth;
using Firebase.Extensions;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AuthManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField emailInputField;
    public InputField passwordInputField;
    public Text messageText;

    private FirebaseAuth auth;

    void Start()
    {
        InitializeFirebase();
    }

    void InitializeFirebase()
    {
        FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
            if (task.Result == DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
                Debug.Log("Firebase initialized successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {task.Result}");
            }
        });
    }

    public void SignUp()
    {
        string email = emailInputField.text;
        string password = passwordInputField.text;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            messageText.text = "Email or Password cannot be empty.";
            Debug.LogError("Email or Password was empty.");
            return;
        }

        Debug.Log($"Attempting to create user with email: {email}");

        auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.LogError("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
                messageText.text = "Sign-up canceled.";
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError($"CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: {task.Exception}");
                messageText.text = "Sign-up error: " + task.Exception;
                return;
            }

            // Firebase user has been created.
            FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result.User;
            Debug.LogFormat("User signed up successfully: {0} ({1})", newUser.Email, newUser.UserId);
            messageText.text = "User signed up: " + newUser.Email;
        });
    }

    public void SignIn()
    {
        string email = emailInputField.text;
        string password = passwordInputField.text;

        Debug.Log($"Attempting to sign in with email: {email}");

        auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
                messageText.text = "Sign-in canceled.";
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError($"SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: {task.Exception}");
                messageText.text = "Sign-in error: " + task.Exception;
                return;
            }

            FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result.User;
            Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})", newUser.Email, newUser.UserId);
            messageText.text = "User signed in: " + newUser.Email;
        });
    }
}


CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (An internal error has occurred.) ---> Firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred.at Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync (System.String email, System.String password) [0x00038] in /Users/runner/work/firebase-unity-sdk/firebase-unity-sdk/macos_unity/x86_64/auth/swig/Firebase.Auth_fixed.cs:3853--- End of inner exception stack trace ------> (Inner Exception #0) Firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred.at Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync (System.String email, System.String password) [0x00038] in /Users/runner/work/firebase-unity-sdk/firebase-unity-sdk/macos_unity/x86_64/auth/swig/Firebase.Auth_fixed.cs:3853 <---


UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)AuthManager:b__6_0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task1<Firebase.Auth.AuthResult>) (at Assets/Scripts/AuthManager.cs:58) Firebase.Extensions.TaskExtension/<>c__DisplayClass4_11<Firebase.Auth.AuthResult>:b__1 () (at /Users/runner/work/firebase-unity-sdk/firebase-unity-sdk/app/task_extension/TaskExtension.cs:128)Firebase.Dispatcher/<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1:b__0 () (at /Users/runner/work/firebase-unity-sdk/firebase-unity-sdk/app/platform/Dispatcher.cs:77)Firebase.ExceptionAggregator:Wrap (System.Action) (at /Users/runner/work/firebase-unity-sdk/firebase-unity-sdk/app/platform/ExceptionAggregator.cs:112)Firebase.Dispatcher:PollJobs () (at /Users/runner/work/firebase-unity-sdk/firebase-unity-sdk/app/platform/Dispatcher.cs:123)Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update () (at /Users/runner/work/firebase-unity-sdk/firebase-unity-sdk/app/platform/Unity/FirebaseHandler.cs:207)Firebase.Platform.FirebaseEditorDispatcher:Update () (at /Users/runner/work/firebase-unity-sdk/firebase-unity-sdk/app/platform/Unity/FirebaseEditorDispatcher.cs:102)UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()


How/Where are you calling SignUp() from?
